# Pandas drop consecutive duplicate rows only, ignoring specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['James', 'James', 'James', 'James',
           'Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max',
           'Park', 'Park','Park', 'Park',
           'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom'],
    'From_num': [578, 420, 420, 'Started', 298, 78, 36, 298, 'Started', 28, 28, 311, 'Started', 60, 520, 99, 'Started'],
    'To_num': [96, 578, 578, 420, 36, 298, 78, 36, 298, 112, 112, 28, 311, 150, 60, 520, 99],
    'Date': ['2020-05-12', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-01', '2019-06-18',
             '2019-08-26', '2019-06-20', '2019-01-30', '2018-10-23',
             '2018-08-29', '2020-05-21', '2020-05-20', '2019-11-22',
             '2019-04-12', '2019-10-16', '2019-08-26', '2018-12-11', '2018-10-09']})
```

and it is like this:

```
       ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James      578      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420     578  2020-02-02
2   James      420     578  2020-02-01 # Drop the this duplicated row (ignore date)
3   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
4     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
5     Max       78     298  2019-06-20
6     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
7     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
8     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
9    Park       28     112  2020-05-21
10   Park       28     112  2020-05-20 # Drop this duplicate row (ignore date)
11   Park      311      28  2019-11-22
12   Park  Started     311  2019-04-12
13    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
14    Tom      520      60  2019-08-26
15    Tom       99     520  2018-12-11
16    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```

There are some consecutive duplicated values (ignore the Date value) within each 'ID'(Name), e.g. line 1 and 2 for James, the From_num are both 420, same as line 9 and 10, I wish to drop the 2nd duplicated row and keep the first. I wrote loop conditions, but it is very redundant and slow, I assume there might be easier way to do this, so please help if you have ideas. Great thanks. The expected result is like this:

```
       ID  From_num  To_num    Date
0   James      578      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420     578  2020-02-02
2   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
3     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
4     Max       78     298  2019-06-20
5     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
6     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
7     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
8    Park       28     112  2020-05-21
9    Park      311      28  2019-11-22
10   Park  Started     311  2019-04-12
11    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
12    Tom      520      60  2019-08-26
13    Tom       99     520  2018-12-11
14    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit late, but does this do what you wanted? This drops consecutive duplicates ignoring "Date".

```
t = df[['ID', 'From_num', 'To_num']]     
df[(t.ne(t.shift())).any(axis=1)]

       ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James      578      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420     578  2020-02-02
3   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
4     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
5     Max       78     298  2019-06-20
6     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
7     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
8     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
9    Park       28     112  2020-05-21
11   Park      311      28  2019-11-22
12   Park  Started     311  2019-04-12
13    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
14    Tom      520      60  2019-08-26
15    Tom       99     520  2018-12-11
16    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```

This drops rows with index values 2 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that's exactly what `DataFrame.drop_duplicates` does, by default it keeps the first occurence and drops the rest

`unique_df = df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'From_num', 'To_num'])`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

**EDIT**

as mentionned in the question, only the consecutive rows should be processed, to do so I propose to flag them first then run drop_duplicates on a subset of the flagged rows ( I'm not sure if it's the best solution )

```
df['original_index'] = null
indices = df.index[1:]
for i in range(1, indices):
    # if current row equals the previous one
    if df.loc[indices[i - 1], 'ID'] == df.loc[indices[i], 'ID'] and df.loc[indices[i -1], 'From_num'] == df.loc[indices[i], 'From_num'] and df.loc[indices[i -1], 'To_num'] == df.loc[indices[i], 'To_num']:
        # get the original index if it has been already set on row index -1
        if df.loc[indices[i - 1], 'original_index'] not null:
            df.loc[indices[i], 'original_index'] = df.loc[indices[i - 1], 'original_index']
        else:
            # else set it to be current index for both rows
            df.loc[indices[i - 1], 'original_index'] = indices[i - 1]
            df.loc[indices[i], 'original_index'] = indices[i - 1]
```

now we add column 'original_index' to drop_duplicates

`unique_df = df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'From_num', 'To_num', 'original_index'])`

Answer (score 0):

Compare the rows below, with the rows above, invert the boolean to get your result:

```
cond1 = df.ID.eq(df.ID.shift())
cond2 = df.From_num.eq(df.From_num.shift())
cond = cond1 & cond2

df.loc[~cond].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternative: longer route :

```
(
    df.assign(
        temp=df.groupby(["ID", "From_num"]).From_num.transform("size"),
        check=lambda x: (x.From_num.eq(x.From_num.shift())) &
                        (x.temp.eq(x.temp.shift())),
    )
    .query("check == 0")
    .drop(["temp", "check"], axis=1)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'From_num', 'To_num']).first().reset_index()
```

Edit - This will remove duplicates even if they are not consecutive. E.g row 4 and 7 in the original df.

**Update**

```
cols=['ID', 'From_num', 'To_num']
df.loc[(df[cols].shift() != df[cols]).any(axis=1)].shape
```